# How to load a file in Pandas from a parent directory

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've not used Pandas in a while but wanted to load a JSON file.

I've traditionally had an overarching directory (on Mac) called DataAnalyis and store all the data I've collected in folders describing what they contain.

I then created a folder called IPythonnotebooks in which I kept my scripts.

Loading a file - let's call it 'dummy.json' was trivial. It's in a folder called dummy.

The code was simple:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('../dummy/dummy.json')
```

That doesn't work any more. What have I got wrong?

Update:

```
DataAnalysis
     ---dummy
       ----dummy.json

     ---IPythonnotebooks
          ----dummy.pynb
```

Apologies if this is not the correct way to present file structure. I start up the notebook file in the folder IPythonnotebooks

Comment: Can you post the file structure?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JupyterLab (and maybe other 'notebooks') start with diff cwd than you might think.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

check if it matches your '../dummy/dummy.json'
or check if this works:

```
import os
fullpath = os.path.realpath("dummy.json")
df = pd.read_json(fullpath)
```